pnpm-lock.yaml removal in nextjs standalone build causes difference in output structure
I have a Yarn workspace project with the following structure
workspaceRoot
  apps
    common
    web-common
    server-common
    chat

The chat project is a NextJS app (14.3). I inadvertently have a pnpm-lock.yaml in the chat project. With the pnpm-lock.yaml (even an empty one), the nextjs standalone build produces the following structure
.next
  standalone
    server.js

If I remove pnpm-lock.yaml, then the output structure is different
.next
  standalone
    common
    web-common
    server-common
    chat
      server.js

I would like to remove the pnpm-lock.yaml and still retain the simpler structure where server.js is directly within the standalone folder. Any help to resolve this weird behaviour is appreciated.
